# How to disable animations for charts in LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I want to disable the animations that are on in the charts in LightningChart JS. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling animations depends on which animations you want to disable.

To disable axis scrolling animation you can use: `axis.setAnimationScroll(undefined)` [setAnimationScroll](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.0.0/classes/axis.html#setanimationscroll)

For xy chart axis zooming `axis.setAnimationZoom(undefined)` [setAnimationZoom](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.0.0/classes/axis.html#setanimationzoom)

For Funnel, Pyramid, Spider, Pie and Gauge charts. `chart.setAnimationsEnabled(false)`