# Line charts performance

Tags: javascript, performance, charts, linechart, lightningchart

I'm trying to get maximum performance for my line charts with LightningChart JS. From the performance example, I learned the max point count I can run with the [performance tester](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-performance/) is **10 series x 1 million point** each. I configure it like this  [image: Configuring JavaScript chart for 10 x 1 million points].

I can run it with 30-40 refreshes / second. 
[image: 10 x 1 M data points scroll monitoring test running]
Two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to test it with higher point counts? Any on-line demo/tester for that?
2. Is there general guidelines for optimizing the performance settings with this JavaScript Lightning Chart?

Answer (score 2):

## Test with more points

There isn't currently any online tester that has higher point counts than that. But the source code for the tester you have used is available in GitHub: https://github.com/Arction/lcjs-performance-tester
The repository has good instructions how to run it locally.

To add a test with more points you can edit the `content/src/tests/default.js` file and add a new test that has the point count you would like to test with. Let's say you would like to have 10 series with 2 million points each. You could add

```js
{
    key: '2M',
    label: '2 M points',
    code: (thickness) => ScrollingProgressiveLine(2 * 1000 * 1000, seriesCount, thickness.thickness, `${seriesCount} Scrolling Line Series 2 000 000 points each ${thickness.label}`),
    defaultSelected: false
},
```

after line 718, between the 1M and 10M points tests. The last test on that list is excluded from being an actual runnable test.

There is also a showcase example that can be used to see how many points the chart can display while maintaining 60 fps. https://arction.github.io/lcjs-showcase-streamingData/

## Optimizing performance

1. Set [DataPattern](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/globals.html#datapatterns) based on the data you are using when creating a new series.

   - For line series it's set with `dataPattern` property in line series options. `chart.addLineSeries({dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive})`
2. Disable animations.

   - I have already answered how to disable animations in [How to disable animations for charts in LightningChart JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370680/how-to-disable-animations-for-charts-in-lightningchart-js).
3. Disable mouse interactions.

   - To disable mouse interactions you can call [.setMouseInteractions(false)](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/chartxy.html#setmouseinteractions) on all axes, series and charts.
4. Disable Auto Cursor.

   - To do this call [setAutoCursorMode](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/chartxy.html#setautocursormode) with [AutoCursorModes.disabled](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/enums/autocursormodes.html#disabled) as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe you could have initialiser/constructor to have this 'OptimalPerformance' mode already set, without having to set these explicitly? Just a thought.