# How to disable zooming animation on loading LIghtningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Please help me in finding way to disable zooming animation. I dont want to disable zooming. I just to disable animations that takes place on zooming in LightningChart JS

Comment: Take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370680/how-to-disable-animations-for-charts-in-lightningchart-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable zooming animations by using [Axis.setAnimationZoom(undefined)](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.2.2/classes/axis.html#setanimationzoom) for all Axes.

```js
// Disable zooming for the default X and Y Axes
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setAnimationZoom(undefined)
chart.getDefaultAxisY().setAnimationZoom(undefined)
```